# Run Sencha Touch 2 build command from an other folder

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a deploy script in which I want to execute the Sencha build command.

Ideally I want to do something like this:

```
sencha app /opt/server/webapps/mybipperapi build production
```

How can I set an absolute path to point to where the sencha command should look for the Sencha app?

Comment: I'v tried this: sencha build -p C:\projectsGit\mybipper\portal\bk-servlets\src\main\webapp -d C:\temp

Comment: And this: sencha build -p C:\projectsGit\mybipper\portal\bk-servlets\src\main\webapp\app.json -d C:\temp

Comment: and this: sencha build -p C:\projectsGit\mybipper\portal\bk-servlets\src\main\webapp\app.js -d C:\temp

Comment: What kind of script is it ? I had a shell script for building my sencha app as well and I just did a 'cd' to the app folder and then called the sencha command. Would it work for you as well ?

Comment: Yes, I also made a ".sh" script, but for some reason it didn't accept the "cd" command, don't remember the exact error message, but it was something Linux specific, something strange since we connect to it from an other machine, not sure. Figuring out how to make that script work is our backup solution. For now i just run the command manually after each deploy.